# Where does "life of Riley" come from?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I heard the saying, "life of Riley" when someone was talking about my cat, and I wondered what the origin of the expression is. The only thing I can think of is that it comes from the name of someone who was pampered and lazy, a king for example.

Comment: see http://phrases.org.uk/meanings/the-life-of-riley.html   
Voting to close.

Comment: @kris. In my view, the site you link to gives very implausible explanations, and does not mention the possibility that the phrase derives from the 'life of _royalty_'  at all (see below).

Comment: The cited etymology never explains the etymology.  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The phrase is frequently said to have originated in the words of a
>   song, but although many songs of the late 19th and early 20th
>   centuries feature a person called Riley or Reilly, none has been
>   identified as furnishing a clear source for the exact phrase. However,
>   the supposedly historical figure of William Reilly (or Riley), an
>   Irishman who eloped with his sweetheart and was saved from execution
>   by her declaration that she had gone with him voluntarily, featured in
>   several popular 18th- and 19th-century ballads (of which Riley and
>   Colinband, ?1795 , may be the earliest to be published), and even a
>   novel by William Carleton ( Willy Reilly, and his dear Coleen Bawn,
>   1855  ), and the following quotation suggests that the phrase may
>   perhaps originally have alluded to him: 1909   Bridgemen's Mag. Aug.
>   486/1   Paddy O'Malley is living the life of Willie Reilly. He has his
>   Colleen Bawn out on a farm [etc.].

Etymological note from the entry on Riley in the online Oxford English Dictionary

Comment: To my way of thinking, this explanation does not make sense.  In Ireland, to say someone is 'living the live of Reilly' means that he or she is having a great life.  My understanding is that the expression comes from 'living the life of _royalty_, meaning that you are living like a royal, and that the expression has change through usage to something that does not quite make sense, in the same way that the (Dublin) expression 'have a canary' (as in my mother will have a canary if she catches us) is derived from 'have a coronary'.